# How to test if strings contain only one difference efficiently?

Tags: java, string

I was asked this question on a technical interview. Question is: given a target, and an array of strings, return an array that contains all strings with ONLY one difference to the target.

For example if target is cat, catt, caT, caa, ca, at <-- are all only one difference. And conversely, cat, cattt, dog, flower, c <-- are not one difference and should not be returned.

oneDiff(String target, String[] a) ...

My approach was:

```
  ans = []
  for all element e in the array
      count -> 0
      if absoulte(e's length - target length) > 1 
          continue
      endif
      for all character c in e
         scan through, increment count if difference is found. 
      endfor
      if (count == 1) 
         continue
      else 
         add e to ans
  endfor
  return ans
```

But the interviewer wasnt happy with what's above. Anyone has any efficient/clever ideas?

Thanks

Comment: Implementing https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Levenshtein_distance should be sufficient.

Comment: What about `ccat`? Should that have a difference of 1?

Comment: @zubergu, LD is ordinarily O(n*m) and has apparently been optimized to O(max(n, m)). Linear scan is O(min(n, m)).

Comment: Why is this tagged as Java? It should be language agnostic.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As mentioned by zubergu Levenshtein distance will solve your problem. You can find Levenshtein distance in java [here](http://rosettacode.org/wiki/Levenshtein_distance#Java).

**Edit:** Since you tagged it as `java` you can run the following java code:

```
public class Levenshtein {

    public static int distance(String a, String b) {
        a = a.toLowerCase();
        b = b.toLowerCase();
        // i == 0
        int [] costs = new int [b.length() + 1];
        for (int j = 0; j < costs.length; j++)
            costs[j] = j;
        for (int i = 1; i <= a.length(); i++) {
            // j == 0; nw = lev(i - 1, j)
            costs[0] = i;
            int nw = i - 1;
            for (int j = 1; j <= b.length(); j++) {
                int cj = Math.min(1 + Math.min(costs[j], costs[j - 1]), a.charAt(i - 1) == b.charAt(j - 1) ? nw : nw + 1);
                nw = costs[j];
                costs[j] = cj;
            }
        }
        return costs[b.length()];
    }

    public static void main(String [] args) {
        String comparison = "cat";
        String [] data = { "cattt", "catt", "caT", "caa", "ca", "at" };
        for (int i = 0; i < data.length; i++)
            System.out.println("distance(" + comparison + ", " + data[i] + ") = " + distance(comparison, data[i]));
    }
}
```

If you run the code you will see the following output:

```
distance(cat, cattt) = 2
distance(cat, catt) = 1
distance(cat, caT) = 0
distance(cat, caa) = 1
distance(cat, ca) = 1
distance(cat, at) = 1
```

If the `distance` is 0 or 1 then its acceptable.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/12597248)

Comment: @ppperry Do you mean that I have to copy paste the code published on the linked page?

Comment: @ppperry I have edited with fully working code based on question.

Comment: Can you specify the running time?

Comment: @jsurf: yet your post now consists almost entirely of a copyrighted work that isn't yours to re-license. Only ever copy information from another site if *properly quoted* and only if a) a small amount of text (to stay within fair use territory) and b) (and this is *important*) **in support of your own original work**. There is nothing here that is your own work.

Comment: @MartijnPieters Since I am a new user, I didn't know that this would be a huge problem. I was asked to put the code here (1st comment). Since you are more experienced (old user) can you suggest/edit the post so it can be eligible to stackoverflow rules? Sorry for any problem.

Comment: @jsurf: np; I know people were falling over you only posting a link. In my opinion (as a community moderator), the link was *fine*. The answer is "Use a Levenshtein distance function*; you can then spruce that up by explaining what that is (summarise / paraphrase a Wikipedia link perhaps) and explain that there are plenty of implementations on the web, with the Rosetta stone link as an example.

Comment: @MartijnPieters Perfect, I am going to do that, I will edit my response based on your suggestions. I will keep in mind your advice for future responses.